# WebApi Telerik Kendo UI Grid with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I've an html page where i've inserted a kendo-grid

```
<kendo-grid options="GridOptions">
</kendo-grid>
```

GridOptions are configured in my angularjs controller (as Telerik suggested)

```
$scope.GridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost/mywebsitename/odata/DentalicaProducts"
            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 5
    },
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true
};
```

When i try to load this page kendo automatically compose the URL for loading grid content:

```
> http://localhost/mywebsitename/odata/DentalicaProducts?$callback=jQuery2…337801940739_1418890531179&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=5
```

But I received this Response:
 - Status Code: 400 Bad Request
and the following Response:

> {
>     "error":{
>       "code":"","message":"The query parameter '$callback' is not supported."
>     }
>   }

My backend service is a webAPI v2.2 service which implements ODataController (v4.0).
If I invoke it directly it works nice and i get my product list.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm guessing that version of web api doesn't do jsonp.  Try adding dataType: 'json' to your dataSource.transport.read object.

Comment: Thx for your suggest. If I add dataType: 'json' it works, but i need to use jsonp for supporting cross-domain request. Is there a way?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to somehow enable jsonp support on web api.  Here is the first one doing a google search.  https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/wiki/JsonpMediaTypeFormatter

Comment: Thx for the response. I've already find this suggestion and i already have a jsonpmediatypeformatter in my service (so i think my service is jsonp enable), but it still not working